# Use of "cintura" and "talle"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Recientemente me encontré con el uso de las palabras "cintura" y "talle" en frases con significados similares. Incluso encontré algunos ejemplos del uso de estas palabras como en las siguientes frases:

> Mi mano **en su **cintura****, me asomé a respirar su alma volátil,
> tan cerca siempre del entreabierto escape.
>
> John se quitó el paliacate y vio a Angela brillando enfrente de él,
> posando con una mano **en su **cintura**** y su otro brazo colgando
> casualmente.
>
> Le puso la mano **en su cintura**, se prendió de él  y atacó los
> primeros compases.
>
> Entonces fue cuando ese tacto de su mano **en su talle** se convirtió
> en  abrazo y en ese momento sus bocas aún rebosantes de miel se
> juntaron.
>
> Y cada dos por tres él la cogía por el brazo o colocaba  su mano **en
> su talle**.

Es común el uso de cualquiera de estas dos palabras en este tipo de situación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personalmente *talle* en esta acepción me suena literario, pero seguramente dependa del dialecto. En Argentina la palabra que se usa es siempre *cintura*. Cuando decimos *talle* es sinónimo de *talla* (medida de la ropa). El otro significado de *talle* perdura en el adjetivo *entallado* (que significa, hablando de un vestido o una prenda similar, "que se ajusta a la cintura").